# How to expand IP Address in dash format?

Tags: shell-script

Sample data

```
10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3
10.100.100.11-10.100.100.15
```

Is there any available trick in Linux to expand this ip to the following format?

```
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3

10.100.100.11
10.100.100.12
10.100.100.13
10.100.100.14
10.100.100.15
```

I know there are online tools such as https://techzoom.net/lab/ip-address-calculator/, but I would like to script this instead of using online tool.

Let me know if there is solution for this (doesn't matter what tool, bash, python or anything)

Comment: so you only want to expand on last digit(s) after last dot? do you know brace expansion? `10.1.1.{1..3}`

Comment: Yup, I do know brace expansion `{1..3}` but it's not applicable as the actual data is more than that.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that allows only the last octet to be a range?

Comment: Your examples aren't common subnets  - can they be presented as something more like 10.1.1.0/30  (which is 0 through 3)    and      10.100.100.8/29  (which would be 8 through 15)    Many tools understand this, which may help your future plans.    (comment because doesn't answer question as asked, but does address the underlying needs)

Comment: @Criggie the netmask tool can convert from one range to the minimal list of blocks but it doesn't allow to just print directly each individual addresses as OP asked. `netmask 10.1.1.1:10.1.1.3` => `10.1.1.1/32` + `10.1.1.2/31`

Answer (score 6):

With `perl`s `Net::IP` module (`libnet-ip-perl` package in Debian based systems):

```
perl -MNet::IP -lne '
  print $an_empty_line unless $. == 1;
  my $ip = Net::IP->new($_);
  do {print $ip->ip} while (++$ip)' < file-with-ip-ranges
```

Answer (score 4):

Too bad that nmap does not support `10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3` format.

```
$ nmap -sL 10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3
Starting Nmap
Failed to resolve "10.1.1.1-10.1.1.3".
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
$
```

But if you can remove the 2nd 3rd octet, and make it like `10.1.1.1-3`, then just use nmap with -sL option

```
$ nmap -sL 10.1.1.1-3 | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
$
```

Answer (score 2):

For multiple ranges:

```
awk -F[.-] '
  {for(i=$1;i<=$5;i++)
    for(j=$2;j<=$6;j++)
      for(k=$3;k<=$7;k++)
        for(l=$4;l<=$8;l++)
          printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", i,j,k,l)}
' file
```

Or at stdin: `echo "range" | awk ...`
Example:

```
echo -n "10.0.1.10-10.1.2.12\n192.168.122.0-192.168.122.3" | awk ...
10.0.1.10
10.0.1.11
10.0.1.12
10.0.2.10
10.0.2.11
10.0.2.12
10.1.1.10
10.1.1.11
10.1.1.12
10.1.2.10
10.1.2.11
10.1.2.12
192.168.122.0
192.168.122.1
192.168.122.2
192.168.122.3
```